# Errors using msxml6.h on visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msxml6

In visual studio 2010 if I start a console project and #include  this works fine, but if I start a win32 project and #include ,it returns many errors during compilation.

Why?

```
Error    1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMImplementation'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    49  1   provamsxml6
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    49  1   provamsxml6
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMImplementation'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    49  1   provamsxml6
Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    49  1   provamsxml6
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    49  1   provamsxml6
Error   6   error C2086: 'int IXMLDOMImplementation' : redefinition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    49  1   provamsxml6
Error   7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMNode' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    55  1   provamsxml6
Warning 8   warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    55  1   provamsxml6
Error   9   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMDocumentFragment' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    61  1   provamsxml6
Warning 10  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    61  1   provamsxml6
Error   11  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMDocument' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    67  1   provamsxml6
Warning 12  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    67  1   provamsxml6
Error   13  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMDocument2'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    73  1   provamsxml6
Warning 14  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    73  1   provamsxml6
Error   15  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMDocument3'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    79  1   provamsxml6
Warning 16  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    79  1   provamsxml6
Error   17  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMNodeList' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    85  1   provamsxml6
Warning 18  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    85  1   provamsxml6
Error   19  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    91  1   provamsxml6
Warning 20  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    91  1   provamsxml6
Error   21  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMCharacterData'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    97  1   provamsxml6
Warning 22  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    97  1   provamsxml6
Error   23  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMAttribute'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    103 1   provamsxml6
Warning 24  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    103 1   provamsxml6
Error   25  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMElement'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    109 1   provamsxml6
Warning 26  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    109 1   provamsxml6
Error   27  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMText' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    115 1   provamsxml6
Warning 28  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    115 1   provamsxml6
Error   29  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IXMLDOMComment'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    121 1   provamsxml6
Warning 30  warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml6.h    121 1   provamsxml6
```

Comment: I only read minds on Mondays.  What errors do you get?

Comment: Can you post an example full code file that works as a console project, buut fails as win32?

Comment: Just start a new project in visual studio then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN in stdafx.h file, remove this entry to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

What is missing is `#include <ole2.h>` or some part there of.
When `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined Ole2 is one of the headers removed from `Windows.h`.
Ole2 can be added back if `INC_OLE2` is defined.

If your providing a header and not sure what the users might define then you could go for safety

```
#if !defined(INC_OLE2) && defined(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
#include <ole2.h>
#endif
#include <msxml2.h>
```